# How to Loop through communities by ID?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, tweets

I am going to find the top 10 hashtags for each of the several thousand communities in my dataset. Each user_name in the dataset, belongs to a specific community (e.g., "a", "b", "c", "d" belong to community 0). A sample of my dataset with only 10 communities looks like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(N = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                  user_name = c("a","b","c","d","e","f", "g", "h", "i", "j"),
                  community_id =c(0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,3),
                  hashtags   = c("#illness, #ebola", "#coronavirus, #covid", "#vaccine, #lie", "#flue, #ebola, #usa", "#vaccine", "#flue", "#coronavirus", "#ebola", "#ebola, #vaccine", "#china, #virus") )
```

To find the top 10 hashtags for EACH community (in the following case, community 0) I need to run the following codes:

```
#select community 0
df_comm_0 <- df %>%
  filter (community == 0)

#remove NAs
df_comm_0 <- na.omit(df_comm_0)

#find top 10 hashtags
df_hashtags_0 <- df_comm_0 %>% 
unnest_tokens(hashtag, hashtags, token = "tweets") %>%
  count(hashtag, sort = TRUE) %>%
  top_n(10)
```

I know using a loop, can save me from running my codes ~15,000 times (number of communities in the dataset). I am not familiar with the loop and even after searching for a couple of hours, was not able to write a loop. The following code is what I wrote which gives me the hashtags for the entire dataset!

```
x <- (df$community_id)

for (val in x) {
  
print (
df %>%
unnest_tokens(hashtag, hashtags, token = "tweets") %>%
  count(hashtag, sort = TRUE) %>%
  top_n(10)
)
}
print()
```

Is there a way I could run the hashtag freqs for all communities by looping through all of them and outputting the top 10 hashtags for each community to 1 file (or separate files)?

Your assistant is much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using `filter(community == 0)` you can use `group_by(community)`, then the following code is executed for every community. However, depending on the size of your dataset, maybe `dplyr` is not feasible and it could be better to use `data.table`

Answer (score 0):

`aggregate`ing by community you may `strsplit` the hashtags at the commas and `unlist` them: The first ten elements of the `names` of a `sort`ed `table` give you the desired top ten hashtags, which you could `paste` back in the original format.

```
aggregate(hash ~ community, df1, function(x)
  paste(names(sort(table(unlist(strsplit(x, ", "))), decreasing=TRUE)[1:5]),
        collapse=", "))
#    community                                                     hash
# 1          1            #covid, #fatalities, #china, #ebola, #illness
# 2          2                  #ebola, #lie, #usa, #covid, #fatalities
# 3          3                #vaccine, #ebola, #farright, #usa, #virus
# 4          4             #china, #vaccine, #flue, #virus, #conspiracy
# 5          5         #illness, #lie, #conspiracy, #ebola, #fatalities
# 6          6         #farright, #fatalities, #china, #ebola, #illness
# 7          7         #virus, #illness, #covid, #conspiracy, #farright
# 8          8                #lie, #china, #flue, #coronavirus, #covid
# 9          9        #conspiracy, #ebola, #fatalities, #farright, #lie
# 10        10 #china, #fatalities, #vaccine, #conspiracy, #coronavirus
```

For sake of clarity I show the top five hashtags, for the top ten use `[1:10]` instead of `[1:5]` in the function.

---

*Data:*

```
n <- 100
df1 <- data.frame(user=1:n, community=rep(1:(n/10), each=10))
set.seed(42)
df1$hash <- 
  replicate(n, paste(sample(c("#illness", "#ebola", "#coronavirus", "#covid",
                              "#vaccine",  "#lie", "#flue", "#usa", "#china",
                              "#fatalities", "#conspiracy", "#farright", 
                              "#virus"), 3), collapse=", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` you could do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(community_id) %>%
  tidytext::unnest_tokens(hashtags, hashtags) %>%
  count(hashtags)%>%
  slice_max(n, n = 5)%>%
  summarise(hashtags = toString(hashtags), .groups = 'drop')
```

Answer (score 0):

Split-apply-combine:

```
tt_by_cid <- Map(function(x){
  head(names(sort(table(unlist(strsplit(x, ", "))), decreasing = TRUE)), 10)}, 
with(df, split(sapply(hashtags, as.character), community_id)))

data.frame(do.call(rbind, mapply(cbind, "community_id" = names(tt_by_cid), 
       hashtags = tt_by_cid, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL)
```